# Путаница со встроенным qSort

Tags: c++, qsort

Здравствуйте! У меня проблема: что-бы сортировка работала правильно мне приходится искуственно увеличивать размер массива! Причём при изменении сортировки на обратный вариант, всё опять перестаёт работать.

Сам код:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int n;
int a[1001];

int cmp(const void *x1, const void *x2);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cin >> n;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cin >> a[i], cout << i << endl;
    qsort(a, n + 1, sizeof(int), cmp);
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        cout << a[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}

int cmp(const void *x1, const void *x2)
{
    return (*(int*)x1 - *(int*)x2);
}
```

Чем вот эта строка

```
qsort(a, n + 1, sizeof(int), cmp);
```

Лучше этой?

```
qsort(a, n, sizeof(int), cmp);
```

Это для меня немного странно, ведь массив я забивал как надо, с нуля, cmp (вспомогательная функция) написал правильно. Такие костыли немного пугают, ведь наверняка в некоторых случаях они портят всё.

Comment: А ничего, что вы выводите массив начиная со второго элемента по `n+1`?

Comment: О, вывожу неправильно О о. Это было для вывода qSort который я писал вручную. Заработал кстати. В любом случае даже после нормального вывода массива первый выводимый элемент приравнялся нулю

Comment: А чему должен быть равен? Приведите пример данных на входе и что получается на выходе.

Comment: Ввод: "5 5 4 3 2 1" Вывод: "1 2 3 4 5" Получилось: "0 2 3 4 5"

Comment: Вывод не повторяется (после изменения индекса начального элемента и количества сортируемых элементов): http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ebc5ff9e9d55ae81

Comment: А нет, проблема опять во мне)) В том примере, который я вам дал, у меня ввод с нуля, а в том, что у меня получилось, ввод с единицы))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обе эти строки плохи, поскольку `qsort` - наследие Си. Когда вы пишете на C++, вам стоит использовать `std::sort`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int n;
int a[1001];

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cin >> n;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cin >> a[i], cout << i << endl;
    sort(a, a + n);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << a[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

*[Выполнить код online](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ebc5ff9e9d55ae81)*

Но на самом деле, проблема не в сортировке, а в выводе элементов:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
//      ^^^^^
```

Вы вводите элементы начиная с нулевого, а выводите с первого.